# Digispark Arduino IDE upload error exit status 0xc0000135

Tags: arduino

When compiling and trying to upload a sketch to standard Digispark Board using Arduino IDE, the following error occurs after the code is compiled:

Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 0xc0000135

I followed all the instructions regarding drivers and the Board URL. So that shouldn't be the issue here